# RabbitMQ spring JAVA Client Stopped consuming messages Resumed on Restart

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using spring-rabbit-1.7.1 library for rabbitmq consumer in java. I have 7 consumers running and same servers are producers as well.
Suddenly consumers stopped consuming messages and resumed when i restarted them.
There were no exceptions and thread dump is as follow:

```
      SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #77 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f497ef34800 nid=0x4e93 waiting on condition [0x00007f490cee6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000064c00bfa0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:439)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1212)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContai

"AMQP Connection 10.66.107.115:5672" #78 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f49901a5000 nid=0x4e94 runnable [0x00007f490cde5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        - locked <0x000000064c3534d0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
```

Producers are working fine as number of messages in queue is creeping up.

Answer (score 0):

The current 1.7.x version is 1.7.10.

Make sure that `enableAutoRecovery` is `false` in the underlying RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory`. It is set to `true` by default in the 4.0.x client; Spring AMQP doesn't need the client auto-recovery because it has had its own recovery mechanism since 1.0.0.

There have been several bug fixes to solve most compatibility problems, but it should be set to `false`. Spring AMQP will disable it automatically, unless you provide a pre-configured RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory` - such as with spring-cloud-connectors on PCF.

This has been fixed in the 2.0.3 version of the connectors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I confirm that enableAutoRecovery is false,I am not passing pre-configured ConnectionFactory.It has been a year now that I am using this setup,this issue occurred first time.I have observed that few connections are idle for 2 days,can it cause some sort of silent connection break?

Comment: Heartbeats are enabled by default to prevent lost connections. Try upgrading to 1.7.10.